# Creating lists of text from rows in a dataframe based on column category

Tags: python, pandas, text

I have a dataframe of categories and text strings:

```
category    strings

pets        leash cat dog
pets        cat dog frog
candy       chocolate frog
candy       jelly beans lollipops
```

I would like 2 lists:

```
petlist = ['leash', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'frog']
candylist = ['chocolate', 'frog', 'jelly', 'beans', 'lollipops']
```

The following code makes one list of all of the words from the strings column:

```
all_words = df['strings'].str.cat(sep=' ').split()
```

How can I split this up into 2 lists based on the category and put the 2 lists in a dictionary?

Here is what I tried:

```
all_words = {}
for cata in df['category']:
    all_words['wordlist_%s'% cata]=[]
for cata in df['category']:
    df_cata = df.loc[df['category'] == cata]
    all_words['wordlist_%s'% cata].append(df_cata['strings'].str.cat(sep=' ').split())
```

It has the correct keys but each key gives me the words from the first row of that category over and over. So I've got a dictionary with one list that says leash cat dog leash cat dog and another list that says chocolate frog chocolate frog (so it's clearly starting over in a way that I don't want it to).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do it

```
df.groupby('category').strings.apply(' '.join).str.split()

category
candy    [chocolate, frog, jelly, beans, lollipops]
pets              [leash, cat, dog, cat, dog, frog]
Name: strings, dtype: object
```

---

***extra credit***
get unique list

```
df.groupby('category').strings.apply(' '.join).str.split().apply(np.unique)

category
candy    [beans, chocolate, frog, jelly, lollipops]
pets                        [cat, dog, frog, leash]
Name: strings, dtype: object
```

---

***over achiever***
`value_counts` because I think it's interesting

```
df.groupby('category').strings.apply(' '.join).str.split(expand=True) \
    .stack().groupby(level=0).apply(pd.value_counts)

 category           
candy     jelly        1
          frog         1
          lollipops    1
          beans        1
          chocolate    1
pets      cat          2
          dog          2
          leash        1
          frog         1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have the code set up to do both of those things at different times. Count frequencies and remove duplicates. I just couldn't get those lists separated and I think your code is probably more efficient for the rest. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the index first then split then group on the index and concatenate all the lists with `sum` and make a dict out of it.

```
df.set_index('category').strings.str.split().groupby(level='category').sum().to_dict()
```

Output

```
{'candy': ['chocolate', 'frog', 'jelly', 'beans', 'lollipops'],
 'pets': ['leash', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'frog']}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer with ' '.join is quite a bit slicker though. Well done! And yes I'll check out the other question.